# Whats a value of x such that both x + 1 == x and x * 2 == x is true?

Tags: c, types, ctf

Title basically says it all. My friend gave me this as a challenge he solved in some CTF he is doing. I have thought about it for a while and can not figure it out. Also, INFINITY isn't a valid answer. Thanks.

Comment: Huh? AFAICT, `x + 1 == x`, (grouped as `(x + 1) == x`) is _always_ false. Full stop. If there _is_ some solution, we'd need more detail (i.e. parentheses) and more elaboration on the equations.

Comment: Probably `float('inf')`

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: The OP ruled that out, even though it seems a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: In some language with a Boolean type, and which also treats any positive number as equivalent to `True`, I can imagine that `x = True` would be a valid solution.  I am not sure what that language would be though (it doesn't work in Python, because it doesn't treat all positive integers as equal to True).

Comment: Minus infinity then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way this happens in C is:

- `x` is an infinity (+∞ or −∞) (equivalently, `HUGE_VAL` or `-HUGE_VAL` in implementations that do not support infinities).
- `x` is a NaN and the C implementation uses non-IEEE-754 behavior for NaNs.
- `x` is adjacent to an infinity in the floating-point representation and a suitable directed rounding mode is used.
- `x+1` and `x*2` overflow and the resulting behavior not defined by the C standard happens to report the comparisons as true.
- `x` is uninitialized and hence indeterminate and takes on different values in the two appearances of `x` in `x+1 == x` such that the comparison is true and, in `x*2 == x` either similarly takes on different values or takes on the value zero.
- `x` is uninitialized and has automatic storage duration and its address is not taken, and hence the behavior is not defined by the C standard, and the resulting behavior happens to report the comparisons as true.

Proof:

Other than infinity, the statements are mathematically false in real numbers, and therefore this cannot arise from real-number behavior. So it must arise from some non-real-number behavior such as overflow, wrapping, rounding, indeterminate values (which may be different in each use of an object) or uninitialized values. Since `*` is constrained to have arithmetic operands, we only need to consider arithmetic types. (In C++, one could define a class to make the comparisons true.)

For signed integers, non-real-number behavior with fully defined values occurs for `+` and `*` only when there is overflow, so that is a possibility.

For unsigned integers, non-real-number behavior with fully defined values occurs for `+` and `*` only when there is wrapping. Then, with wrapping modulo *M*, we would have *x*+1 = *x*+*kM* for some integer *k*, so 1 = *kM*, which is not possible for any *M* used in wrapping.

For the `_Bool` type, exhaustive testing of the possible values eliminates them.

For floating-point numbers, non-real-number behavior with fully defined values occurs for `+` and `*` only with rounding, underflow, and overflow and with NaNs. NaNs never compare as equal by IEEE-754 rules, so they cannot satisfy this, except for the fact that the C standard does not require IEEE-754 conformance, so an implementation could choose to make the comparisons true.

`x*2` will not underflow, since it increases the magnitude. `x+1` can be made to underflow in a perverse floating-point format with smaller exponent range than precision, but this will not produce `x+1 == x`. `x+1 == x` can be satisfied by rounding for sufficiently large `x`, but then `x*2` must produce a value other than `x`.

That leaves overflow. If `x` is the greatest representable finite number (and hence the greatest representable number less than infinity), and the rounding mode is downward (toward −∞) or toward zero, then `x+1` will yield `x` and `x*2` will yield `x`, so the comparisons yield true. Similarly, the greatest negative representable finite number will satisfy the comparisons with rounding upward (toward +∞) or toward zero.

Answer (score 6):

The equalities will hold true for `double x = HUGE_VAL;`. Since C99, quoting [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL):

> The `HUGE_VALF`, `HUGE_VAL` and `HUGE_VALL` macros expand to positive floating point constant expressions which compare equal to the values returned by floating-point functions and operators in case of overflow

Sample code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x = HUGE_VAL;
    printf("%d %d\n", x + 1 == x, 2 * x == x);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/cPPc1G5EE):

```
1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Solving for `x` using the C preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

#define x  1,1

    if (x + 1 == x)
        printf("x + 1 == x is true\n");

    if (x * 2 == x)
        printf("x * 2 == x is true\n");

    printf("x     = %d\n", x);
    printf("x + 1 = %d\n", x + 1);
    printf("x * 2 = %d\n", x * 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output (warnings omitted :):

```
x + 1 == x is true
x * 2 == x is true
x     = 1
x + 1 = 1
x * 2 = 1
```